# Javafx Label losing text format

Tags: javafx, label, javafx-8

The intent is simply to grab some already spaced out text from a file, and display all the lines in a label.  However, even though the text is properly spaced in the file and read as such, it seems to lose the spacing when put into a label, and I can't figure out why.

[Text in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWDmN.png)

[How it appears in the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYdsp.png)

Here's the code snippet that reads from the file and creates the label

```
//read through each line in the file and add it to the string
    String filename = recordsListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
    String filecontents = "";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            filecontents+=line+"\n";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        filecontents = "File corrupt or not found.";
    }
    //create the window to show
    Stage dialog = new Stage();
    dialog.setTitle("File: "+filename);
    //utility style has the basic window decorations
    dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText(filecontents);
    //set id to mark for a css property
    label.setId("popupLabel");
    ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
    sp.setContent(label);
    Scene scene = new Scene(sp);
    scene.getStylesheets().clear();
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource(cssSheet).toExternalForm());
    dialog.setScene(scene);
    dialog.setWidth(300);
    dialog.setHeight(250);
    //NONE allows the window to be treated as a seperate window, and the windows underneath can still have events triggered
    dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE);
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Isn't this just because of the font? (I.e. your file viewer is using a monospaced font and your label isn't?)

Comment: Oh wow, I wasn't even thinking about that.  Thank you so much!